# How to get current date in DDMMYY format and split them into DD, MM and YY using C#?

Tags: c#

This is what i could write?

```
string text = string.Format("{0:d/MM/yy}", DateTime.Now.Date);
text = text.Replace("-", "");
char[] cString = text.ToCharArray();
string year = text.Substring(text.Length - 2);
string month = cString[2].ToString() + cString[3].ToString();
string day = cString[0].ToString() + cString[1].ToString();
```

Please help me find the mistake as it is not getting displayed correctly on my Win Form Application. It is showing 01 05 13 as 10 __ 13.

Comment: @snumpy just after posting this question i got this and corrected my code. A silly mistake. But here i got so many shorter ways to do that. Thanks a lot everyone. You all are Gods of coding.

Comment: @snumpy the mistake i mentioned was in my actual code. I was referring to that only and not my post. Its working now as i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
int year = today.Year;
int month = today.Month
int day = today.Day;
```

Comment: Phew. The other answers were beginning to worry me there for a moment. All those ToString()... :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do that like this:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
var parts = date.ToString("d MM yy").Split(" "); // dd MM yy for 2-digit day
var year = parts[2];
var month = parts[1];
var day = parts[0];
```

But this seems even easier:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
var year = date.ToString("yy");
var month = date.ToString("MM");
var day = date.ToString("d");  // dd for 2-digit day
```

Comment: don't see why that's so bad, it really comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Why not implicit typing. It is a totally valid idea especially when it is not in a high performance section of code.

Comment: @Esoteric Why not? It's plainly obvious what those types are.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, why not?

Comment: @Nomad101 Implicit typing has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: Personally, unless there's a cast / conversion or I use new to initialize a variable, I avoid implicit typing but there's definitely nothing wrong with using it.

Comment: @Nomad101, performance has nothing to do with it, `var` is used at compile not runtime.

Comment: @Nomad101 What do you mean, "high performance"? They were talking about the `var` keyword.

Comment: I was always under the impression, due to performance profiliers, which not saying I was right or anything, that var's tend to slow down code.

Comment: Maybe you got confused with `dynamic`. `var` is simply syntactic sugar around static typing

Comment: @Nomad101 `var` is a nothing more than language feature. Once it's compiled, it's identical to explicit typing.

Comment: @Tejas Very possible, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Nomad101 As others have said, `var` has nothing to do with performance. The type is figured out at COMPILE TIME. The ONLY thing a `var` would slow down is time to compile.

Comment: @tnw why post exactly what others have posted I was mistaken and already figured out the issue.

Comment: @Nomad101 I was responding to `var's tend to slow down code.`, several comments got posted between the time I started writing my comment and submitted.

Comment: Seemed to me like implicit typing could add confusion for someone cutting their teeth, since this is a relatively basic question. It will of course work just fine. As @Tejas said, personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do:

```
DateTime currDate = DateTime.Now;

string year = currDate.ToString("yy");
string month = currDate.ToString("MM");
string day  currDate.ToString("d");
```

or just

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("d MM yy");
```